# R check if an element exists in the dataframe and return its index

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
index     id
1         abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno
2         bcd;efg;hij;klm;nop
3         cde;fgh;ijk;lmn;opq
.
.
.
```

I would like to use R to find if "abc" is in the dataframe and return its index.

I have tried to separate the 'id' column to 5 different columns and to find whether "abc" is in each row. But my dataset contains about 200,000 rows. It takes so long to loop through every row. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to detect it.

For example, "abc" is part of df$id[1], then the result should return 1;
"cde" should return 3.

Comment: not sure if this is what you want? `grep("abc", df$id)` would return index in `id` where "abc" is present.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `which` function in combination with `grepl` like this:

```
which(grepl("abc", df$id))
```

`grepl` returns `TRUE` if "abc" is contained in a string and `FALSE` otherwise.
`which` returns the index of entries which contain `TRUE`.

Or even easier with `grep`:

```
grep("abc", df$id)
```

Comment: as was mentioned in the comments on the OP, you can just use plain `grep` and that will return the index, i.e. `grep("abc",df$id)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(stringr)

df[str_detect(df$id, "abc"), "index"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a `%g%` operator lately (inspired by `%in%`) to do this type of thing:

```r
library(tidyverse)

`%g%` <- function(x,y) {
  z <- paste0(y, collapse = "|")
  grepl(z, x, ignore.case = T)
}

df <- read.table(h = T,
                 stringsAsFactors = F,
                 text = "index     id
                         1         abc;def;ghi;jkl;mno
                         2         bcd;efg;hij;klm;nop
                         3         cde;fgh;ijk;lmn;opq")

df %>% 
  filter(id %g% "abc") %>% 
  pull(index)
#> [1] 1

df %>% 
  filter(id %g% "cde") %>% 
  pull(index)
#> [1] 3
```

This supports multiple values as well:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(id %g% c("abc", "cde")) %>% 
  pull(index)
#> [1] 1 3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>